# Как получить подпись (название) поля из кода в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Есть пользовательское поле UF_TASK_EFFICIENCY именуемое как Оперативность.

Как вывести эту саму подпись в нужном месте, имея XML_ID его?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод [CUserTypeEntity::GetList](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cusertypeentity/getlist.php) для получения информации по пользовательским полям. Например, в вашем случае получится примерно так:

```
$fieldName = "";
$rsUserField = CUserTypeEntity::GetList(
    [], 
    [
        'XML_ID' => 'UF_TASK_EFFICIENCY'
    ]
);
if($arUserField = $rsUserField->Fetch()) {
     $fieldName = $arUserField['FIELD_NAME'];
}
```

Comment: Выводит UF_TASK_EFFICIENCY

Comment: Ожидалось - Оперативность

Comment: Читаем длкументацию. И о чудо там есть фраза "Внимание! При не указание в фильтре ключа LANG со значением необходимого языка ('LANG' => 'ru'), поля "Подпись в форме редактирования", "Заголовок в списке" и т.д. не будут участвовать в выборке. ([EDIT_FORM_LABEL], [LIST_COLUMN_LABEL], [LIST_FILTER_LABEL], [ERROR_MESSAGE], [HELP_MESSAGE])"